# TeamCity: How to show Nunit3 file attachments in TeamCity test results?

Tags: nunit, teamcity, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

NUnit3 recently added a functionality to add attachments to test results using `TestContext.AddTestAttachment()`. This adds a url\filelink of the file in results. I can see the entry in Test Result XML generated by console runner.

But I do not see the attachment link on Teamcity. How can I force teamcity to display the file links added as attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, TeamCity haven't yet implemented any functionality to display test attachments.

You should make a feature request for that, [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW). You could add to your case by pointing out that VSTS does display these file attachments. ;-)